# How can I reflectively call a method on a Scala object from Java?

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I have a scala object defined like the following:

```
package com.example

object Foo {
  def bar(): String = "Interesting Result"
}
```

I know that I can call `Foo$.MODULE$.bar()` from Java if `Foo` is in the build and runtime classpath, but in my situation `Foo` is not in the build classpath and may or may not be configured in the runtime classpath.

From my Java code I'd like to use reflection to call `bar()` if it is available on the runtime classpath, otherwise I'll fall back to a default implementation.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with code that looks something like this:

```
package com.example.java;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Example {

  /**
   * Returns null or the result of calling a method on a scala object from java
   */
  public String callScalaFromJava(){
    String result = null;

    try {
      Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.example.Foo$"); // Note the trailing '$'
      Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("bar");
      Field field = clazz.getField("MODULE$");
      Object instance = field.get(null);
      Object obj = method.invoke(instance, new Object[] {});

      if (obj instanceof String) {
        result = (String) obj);
      }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // SWALLOWING
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for reflection. The code can be accessed directly via either `Foo.bar()` or `Foo$.MODULE$.bar()`.

Answer (score 2):

The object Foo class is `com.example.Foo$` so if you can just load that class, everything will go fine without using reflection:

```
try { 
    Class.forName("com.example.Foo$");
    String s = com.example.Foo$.MODULE$.bar();
    // ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
  String s = // fallback solution
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by David Carlson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529362/how-can-i-reflectively-call-a-method-on-a-scala-object-from-java/26835674#answer-6529367) I created this utility class for calling methods on Scala objects reflectively.
The class lets you also call Scala methods that expect parameters.

I put it here in the hope that it's useful to somebody and to get feedback on how to improve the code.

ScalaUtil.java:

```
package your.stuff.utils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
// I use SLF4J (http://www.slf4j.org/) for logging. Feel free to change this
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/** Utilities for Scala/Java integration */
public class ScalaUtil {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScalaUtil.class);

    /**
     * Calls the parameterless {@code method} on a Scala {@code object}.
     * <p>
     * Returns an object of type {@code ReturnType} if the call succeeded, null
     * otherwise.
     *
     * @param object
     *            the fully qualified path to the object such as
     *            "eu.test.MyScalaObj$". Mind the dollar sign at the end
     * @param method
     *            the name of the method inside {@code object} we want to call
     * @param <ReturnType>
     *            type of the return value of the {@code method}
     * @return the return value of the Scala {@code object}'s {@code method} or
     *         null if the {@code method} couldn't be called
     */
    public static <ReturnType> ReturnType callObj(final String object,
            final String method) {
        final Object noParams[] = {};
        return callObj(object, method, noParams);
    }

    /**
     * Calls a {@code method} on a Scala {@code object} with the given method
     * {@code arguments}.
     * <p>
     * Returns an object of type {@code ReturnType} if the call succeeded, null
     * otherwise.
     *
     * @param object
     *            the fully qualified path to the object such as
     *            "eu.test.MyScalaObj$". Mind the dollar sign at the end
     * @param method
     *            the name of the method inside {@code object} we want to call
     * @param arguments
     *            the arguments that {@code method} expects
     * @param <ReturnType>
     *            type of the return value of the {@code method}
     * @return the return value of the Scala {@code object}'s {@code method} or
     *         null if the {@code method} couldn't be called
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <ReturnType> ReturnType callObj(final String object,
            final String method, final Object... arguments) {
        ReturnType result = null;
        Class<?> objClass = null;
        try {
            final Class<?>[] methArgTypes = getTypes(arguments);
            objClass = Class.forName(object);
            final Method meth = objClass
                    .getDeclaredMethod(method, methArgTypes);
            final Field field = objClass.getField("MODULE$");
            final Object instance = field.get(null);
            result = (ReturnType) meth.invoke(instance, arguments);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SecurityException
                | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException
                | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            LOG.warn("Could not call method {} on {} with arguments {}",
                    method, object, arguments, e);
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
            if (objClass != null) {
                LOG.info("Declared methods: {}",
                        (Object[]) objClass.getDeclaredMethods());
            }
            LOG.warn("Could not call method {} on {} with arguments {}",
                    method, object, arguments, e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the runtime types of some {@code objects}.
     *
     * @param objects
     *            the objects in whose types we are interested in
     * @return an array of the runtime types of the {@code objects}
     */
    private static Class<?>[] getTypes(final Object... objects) {
        final Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[objects.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            final Object o = objects[i];
            final Class<?> type = o.getClass();
            types[i] = type;
        }
        return types;
    }

    /** This utility class is not meant to be instantiated */
    private ScalaUtil() {
    }
}
```

In order to call the Scala method with parameters you'll need to add the Scala library to the build path of your Java project.

Assuming this is the Scala object you want to call:

```
package eu.tests.scala
object ScalaObject {

  // You'll have to use Java's boolean when Java calls this
  def sayHello(param: java.lang.Boolean): String = "param: " + param

  def sayHello: String = "no param"

  def sayHello(param: String): String = "param: " + param
}
```

This is how you use the ScalaUtil on the above Scala object:

```
String scalaPackage = "eu.tests.scala";
String scalaObject = "ScalaObject";
String method = "sayHello";
String fullScalaObjName = scalaPackage + "." + scalaObject + "$";

String result1 = ScalaUtil.callObj(fullScalaObjName, method);
String result2 = ScalaUtil.callObj(fullScalaObjName, method, true);
String result3 = ScalaUtil.callObj(fullScalaObjName, method, "abc");
```